# Div not appearing in Chrome only

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, bootstrap-4

I have an HTML/CSS chat that I'm in the process of making work through the WebSocket API, but I'm hitting an issue with Chrome only 
(I tested this to work okay in Firefox, Brave, Safari) where the div containing my input field and my send button is just not shown at all on the page.

This is what it looks like in Chrome

[image: Chrome]

And now in other browsers

[image: Other browsers]

```css
body {
  background: #ddd;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

label {
  color: rgba(120, 144, 156, 1.0) !important;
}

.btn:focus,
.btn:active:focus,
.btn.active:focus {
  outline: none !important;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 0px rgba(120, 144, 156, 1.0) inset, 0 0 0px rgba(120, 144, 156, 0.8);
}

textarea:focus,
input[type="text"]:focus,
input[type="password"]:focus,
input[type="datetime"]:focus,
input[type="datetime-local"]:focus,
input[type="date"]:focus,
input[type="month"]:focus,
input[type="time"]:focus,
input[type="week"]:focus,
input[type="number"]:focus,
input[type="email"]:focus,
input[type="url"]:focus,
input[type="search"]:focus,
input[type="tel"]:focus,
input[type="color"]:focus,
.uneditable-input:focus {
  border-color: rgba(120, 144, 156, 1.0);
  color: rgba(120, 144, 156, 1.0);
  opacity: 0.9;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 0px rgba(120, 144, 156, 1.0) inset, 0 0 10px rgba(120, 144, 156, 0.3);
  outline: 0 none;
}

.card::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 1px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 9px;
  background: rgba(96, 125, 139, 0.99);
}

.balon1,
.balon2 {
  margin-top: 5px !important;
  margin-bottom: 5px !important;
}

.balon1 a {
  background: #42a5f5;
  color: #fff !important;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 3px 20px;
  display: block;
  max-width: 75%;
  padding: 7px 13px 7px 13px;
}

.balon1:before {
  content: attr(data-is);
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: -0.8em;
  display: block;
  font-size: .750rem;
  color: rgba(84, 110, 122, 1.0);
}

.balon2 a {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  color: #000 !important;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 3px;
  display: block;
  max-width: 75%;
  padding: 7px 13px 7px 13px;
}

.balon2:before {
  content: attr(data-is);
  position: absolute;
  left: 13px;
  bottom: -0.8em;
  display: block;
  font-size: .750rem;
  color: rgba(84, 110, 122, 1.0);
}

.bg-sohbet:before {
  content: "";
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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');
  opacity: 0.06;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="jumbotron m-0 p-0 bg-transparent">
  <div class="row m-0 p-0 position-relative">
    <div class="col-12 p-0 m-0 position-absolute" style="right: 0px;">
      <div class="card border-0 rounded" style="box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10), 0 6px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01); overflow: hidden; height: 100vh;">
        <div class="card-header p-1 bg-light border border-top-0 border-left-0 border-right-0" style="color: rgba(96, 125, 139,1.0);">
          <img class="rounded float-left" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/5c/24/69/5c24695df36eee73abfbdd8274085ecd--cute-anime-guys-anime-boys.jpg" />
          <h6 class="float-left" style="margin: 0px; margin-left: 10px;"> Yusuf Bulgurcu <i class="fa fa-check text-primary" title="Onaylanmış Hesap!" aria-hidden="true"></i> </br>
            <small> İstanbul, TR</small>
          </h6>
          <div class="dropdown show">
            <a id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-sm float-right text-secondary" role="button">
              <h5><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h" title="Ayarlar!" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;
              </h5>
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right border p-0" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
              <a class="dropdown-item p-2 text-secondary" href="#"> <i class="fa fa-user m-1" aria-hidden="true"></i> Profile
              </a>
              <hr class="my-1"></hr>
              <a class="dropdown-item p-2 text-secondary" href="#"> <i class="fa fa-trash m-1" aria-hidden="true"></i> Delete </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card bg-sohbet border-0 m-0 p-0" style="height: 100vh;">
          <div id="sohbet" class="card border-0 m-0 p-0 position-relative bg-transparent" style="overflow-y: auto; height: 100vh;">
            <div class="balon1 p-2 m-0 position-relative" data-is="You - 3:20 pm">
              <a class="float-right"> Hey there! What's up? </a>
            </div>
            <div class="balon2 p-2 m-0 position-relative" data-is="Yusuf - 3:22 pm">
              <a class="float-left sohbet2"> Checking out this awesome chat design.. </a>
            </div>
            <div class="balon1 p-2 m-0 position-relative" data-is="You - 3:23 pm">
              <a class="float-right"> Christ, you know who made that? </a>
            </div>
            <div class="balon2 p-2 m-0 position-relative" data-is="Yusuf - 3:26 pm">
              <a class="float-left sohbet2"> Well I can think of only one person capable of this... </a>
            </div>
            <div class="balon1 p-2 m-0 position-relative" data-is="You - 3:28 pm">
              <a class="float-right"> Oh no it can't </a>
            </div>
            <div class="balon2 p-2 m-0 position-relative" data-is="Yusuf - 3:33 pm">
              <a class="float-left sohbet2"> Yes, him. </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w-100 card-footer p-0 bg-light border border-bottom-0 border-left-0 border-right-0">
          <form class="m-0 p-0" autocomplete="off">
            <div class="row m-0 p-0">
              <div class="col-9 m-0 p-1">
                <input id="text" class="mw-100 border rounded form-control" type="text" name="text" title="Type a message..." placeholder="Type a message..." required>
              </div>
              <div class="col-3 m-0 p-1">
                <button type="button" id="send" class="btn btn-outline-secondary rounded border w-100" title="Gönder!" style="padding-right: 16px;"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"
                                                                        aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sockjs-client@1/dist/sockjs.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: my first though is that the div with this class `card bg-sohbet border-0 m-0 p-0` have `height: 100vh`, so it is pushing `.card-footer` out of screen

Comment: Looks like the height on #sohbet is 100vh. Lessen that and your chatbox shows. At 100vh you're taking the entire available height and pushing the chatbox below the screen.

Comment: Oh my.. thanks, can't figure out why 100vh behaves differently on chrome though :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your div containing the `#sohbet` element has a height of `100vh` set and its parent div has `overflow:hidden` set. Therefore, the form gets pushed out of the divs bounds and is invisble to the user. 
Chrome renders your layout correctly, apparently the other browsers seem to be wrong here.

Fix the problem by decreasing the height. You can e.g. calculate the height, if your header and form have a fixed height by using `calc`

```
<div style="height: calc(100vh - <HeightOfHeaderAndForm>);"
```

You can also use flexbox to fill the available space. I recommend you check out this excellent guide: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Thank you very much, I finally ended up using this :
`<div class="card bg-sohbet border-0 m-0 p-0" style="height: calc(100vh - 105px);">`

Answer (score 0):

Please add this CSS in your code

```css
.card-footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem. sorry. See above for the right fix.